# Validation rule that requires a picklist value in a contact record once a picklist value in an opportunity record is selected

Tags: validation, validation-rule

Is there anyway to make a contact record picklist value (Customer) become a required selection once a opportunity record picklist value (Closed Won) is selected?

I ask because sales reps forget to mark the contact record as a Customer once the opportunity becomes Closed Won. Perhaps there is a way for an error message to occur if the picklist value is NOT a customer once the picklist value Closed Won is selected.

Answer (score 5):

I would approach this a different way.  Create your  picklist on the Account record instead. It is the business that is your customer, the Contact just works there.  Use a cross object formula to display the Account value on the Contact record.  (I'm also thinking that there may be multiple Contact records under the Account.)  Then create a Opportunity workflow rule, set it fire when Opportunity: Won equals True.  Associate a Field Update that will update the Account picklist to Customer.  The formula on the Contact will now display "Customer".

hth.

Aiden

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you have a lookup from Opportunity to Contact? Perhaps a validation rule is the wrong way to do this. The issue is going to be that you have to put the validation rule on the Opportunity. This would prevent the user from closing the Opportunity if the Contact hasn't been marked as a customer. The user would then have to navigate to the Contact, update it first and then go back to the opportunity and close it.

A friendlier flow for the user would be to automatically update the contact when the Opportunity is marked as Closed Won.

I'd probably use Process Builder to do the contact update. Note that Process Builder is still in Beta - you need to contact support to get it enabled. Flow would be another non-code option.